# why Java Script nested loop gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I have nested arrays which i want to list the children who belong to their parenets.

But the result obviously has gone wrong, it lists all the children in the array even they don't belong to the parents.

Just can't work out what's gone wrong.

```js
var family = [ 
 { name:"parentOne",
   children:[ "John", "jack"]
},
 { name:"parentTw0",
   children: [ "jane", "joe"]
},
 { name:"parentThree",
   children: [ "Terry", "Noah"]
},
]

all = "";
childAll = "";
for (i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < family[i].children.length; j++) {
        childAll += family[i].children[j] +"<br>" ;
    }

  all += family[i].name + "<br>" + " " + childAll + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = all;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You need to reset `childAll` in the beginning of the outer loop, not before loops. At the moment you accumulate all the children in that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not reset the childAll.

```
all = "";
childAll = "";
for (i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
    // After one loop the childAll contains all the previous ones
    for (j = 0; j < family[i].children.length; j++) {
        childAll += family[i].children[j] +"<br>" ;
    }

  all += family[i].name + "<br>" + " " + childAll + "<br>";
}
```

Should be

```
all = "";
for (i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
    // Reset every loop
    childAll = "";

    for (j = 0; j < family[i].children.length; j++) {
        childAll += family[i].children[j] +"<br>" ;
    }

  all += family[i].name + "<br>" + " " + childAll + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `childAll = ""` inside the 1st for loop since you want to start with an empty list for each parent.